# How to start Chromium on 2 displays?

Tags: multiple-monitors, chromium

We are using a Zotac with a display connected to each video port (HDMI
and DVI). When the Zotac boots, we want to open a Chromium browser
that covers the two displays.

(As context, we have placed the two displays side by side. They are
used to display a scoreboard in a sports facility. The scoreboard is
implemented in a Web page displayed by Chromium. See http://www.softpeelr.com/img/displays.jpg).

The problem is that when the browser starts, we can only get it to
resize to one display. When we manually resize the browser to cover
the two displays, and reboot the Zotac, the settings are not
remembered and on reboot, the browser is maximized on one display. We
have tried resizeTo() in JavaScript and the --window-size command line
option, but this has not worked.

We are running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: which vga is used in you zotac?

Comment: First, I would highly recommend upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, as 12.04 will be EOL in 3 months. As for the graphics, are you using the proprietary NVidia drivers for the GPU? Or are you relying on the open source drivers?

Comment: Thanks for speedy reply. It's an NVidia driver. The `lspci` command: 02:00.0 "VGA compatible controller" "NVIDIA Corporation" "GF119M [GeForce GT 520M]" -ra1 "ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd." "Device 2180"